# Azure Web App on Linux with 502 proxy error

Tags: node.js, linux, azure, azure-web-app-service

Here is my issue
I deployed an existing Nodejs api app from Azure Web App to Azure Web App on Linux. The reason for the test is to confirm the performance on Web App is the same regardless of OS.(I always think it will run faster in Linux). After the deployment, I am testing a GET with http:///api/{the rest of the query}, which had been configured in the route of NodeJS.

As the result of the GET query, I am getting the following error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>502 Proxy Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Proxy Error</h1>
        <p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.
            <br />
The proxy server could not handle the request
            <em>
                <a href="/api/restaurantlist">GET&nbsp;/api/restaurantlist</a>
            </em>.
            <p>
Reason: 
                <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong>
            </p>
        </p>
        <hr>
        <address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at vivaapitest Port 80</address>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope you can assist me if I need to configure .htcaccess for the aparche redirect changes
Any assistance or advice will appreciate!. Thank you.

Comment: Any error logs from the API?

Answer (score 0):

The error `5xx` indicates server-side errors. You could capture error logs by using [Azure CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli), then see what logs say. For more details, please refer to [Capturing stdout in Azure Linux App Service via NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44419932/capturing-stdout-in-azure-linux-app-service-via-nodejs/44425488#44425488).

Also, note that Azure Web App on Linux that host Node.js applications use PM2 to manage Node.js process. So, you may need to [specify the PM2 configuration file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-using-nodejs-pm2) (not `.htcaccess`) to use for your Node.js app.

Comment: thank you. I will double check that. It seems running now, but not returning any data.

Comment: Hi, I tried, unfortunately, I am not getting anything back from the log. Just constantly getting 502 error when I start to call the blueprint api from SailsJS framework.